# Is possible code haskell and run it in github codespace?

Tags: github, haskell, virtual, haskell-stack, github-codespaces

I am discovering the github codespace and I think it is a wonderful tool to code and practice coding.
As far as I know, the codespace can run python, java, js and html natively. Searching about the subject, I found things that make me believe it can run go, rust and a bunch of anothers.
But here is my question, can codespace run haskell as well?

I have looked for solutions for a time already, but I did not find anything that can help me about the problem.

Comment: You can define the environment by means of a [dev container](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers), where you can put pretty much anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely can.  You can install Haskell as you would on any other Linux system, enable the Haskell extension in Visual Studio, and code away.

Depending on your Haskell setup, it might take a long time to build all the libraries you depend on, e.g., when using Stack, in which case you might want to use a [prebuilt image](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/prebuilding-your-codespaces/about-github-codespaces-prebuilds) by setting up a [dev container](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers).  I have such a [setup](https://github.com/chungyc/site-personal/blob/main/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json) myself in one of my projects, although I haven't been able to reduce the size of the prebuilds much.